# Conda Using Wrong Path to urls.txt

Tags: python, linux, conda, environment

Currently trying to create a new conda environment using `conda create --name <env_name>`.
I am making this environment on a linux server that I have ssh'ed into, and my user on that server has anaconda installed in the directory `/home/<username>/`.

When I try to create the conda environment, I get the error:

```
NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path.
  path: /Users/<personal_username>/anaconda3/pkgs/urls.txt
  uid: 1004
  gid: 1004

If you feel that permissions on this path are set incorrectly, you can manually
change them by executing

  $ sudo chown 1004:1004 /Users/<personal_username>/anaconda3/pkgs/urls.txt

In general, it's not advisable to use 'sudo conda'.
```

The issue I've noted is that the username in the error message corresponds to my username on my personal computer instead of on the linux server. How can I change what path it uses so it uses the path on the linux server instead of the one on my personal computer?

If I can provide any other helpful information let me know.

Edit: On the directories on my personal computer, the directory `/Users/<personal_username>/anaconda3` does not exist.

Comment: Sounds general computing problem to me. Something with the SSH or terminal. Conda just follows what the shell tells it. Is your SSH connection explicitly using the remote username?

Comment: I believe so. The command whoami returns the correct username and it shows the correct name in the <username>@server portion before the dollar sign.

Comment: Maybe grep for any environment variables that have it, e.g., `env | grep 'personal_username'`. Show `conda info` output. Check `~/.condarc` file for something cached in the settings.

Comment: ahh, yes in ~/.condarc the first path in envs_dirs is the wrong path. I just need to change it and it should work.